# Python Counting the exchanges in a selection sort

Tags: python-3.x, swap, cumulative-sum, selection-sort

I apologize as this is my first question on this site and it is extremely basic, but I am somewhat lost in a current lab I am trying to complete.

Currently I am attempting to count the amount of exchanges(Or swaps? Not sure on the right word there!) during a selection sort throughout the passes.

Now according to my current understanding, the replacement section of our formula is traversing my list. However, it doubles the amount of swaps it is actually supposed to be spitting back at me. Now this would lead me to believe an if statement might need to be operating in the outer loop, but that doesn't seem quite right to me.

An example of what I have done to cause this problem below. I am curious if I am on the right path or should I slash and burn or go back to the drawing board.

The reason I am counting them independently is I am displaying when there is a swap then a grand total of all the swaps. Which I find to be a bit ironic as with a selection sort you can only have 1 swap per pass?

Any case, I apologize for the rather basic question, but I seem to be missing something so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction of if I should be focusing on the outer loop to determine the exchanges?

```
print( "Original list:" , a_list, "\n" )
count =1   
n = len(a_list)
comp = n -1
exchanges=1
comp_total=0
exch_total=0

for end in range(n, 1, -1):      # Each pass starts here
    #Setting our running total to adjust for previous value.
    comp_total +=comp-(count-1)
    print("Pass", count, ":", "Comparisons:",comp-(count-1), "\tExchanges:", exchanges,"\n", end="\t ")
    count += 1
    # --- Search for Largest ---
    min_position = 0

    for i in range(1, end):
        if a_list[i] > a_list[min_position]:   # Perform n
            min_position = i
            exchanges = 0
            exch_total +=1

        else:
            exchanges = 1






    # --------------------------

    temp = a_list [end - 1]        # Perform exchange
    a_list [end - 1] = a_list [min_position]
    a_list [min_position] = temp
    print(a_list)
    print()

print("\tTotal Comparisons:",comp_total, "Total Exchanges:", exch_total)
```

selection_sort(a_list)

Comment: Where are you doing the actual swap? There are a number of variables not defined, which makes it very hard to test your code, please read [mcve].

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The [edit] button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: My bad, so AChampion, just a brief explanation of my basic understanding, anything happening within the if statement should be only occur during the swap? Correct? Granted, if it traverses over multiple lesser values, that could be tripping it as well... AHhh.

Answer (score 0):

In this case,

My issue was the the fact my print statement was before the actual loop, this was throwing off my count, by placing the if statement past this point, I was able to get an accurate running total!

Cheers!